# Unexpected (?) Typescript behaviour, can someone explain?

Tags: typescript

Came across this weird bug in our code, that wasn't picked up by TS.

I have simplified it for demonstration.

The two objects are merged by spreading their values into an object. (this was the bug).

When you spread arrays into objects, the key is the index.

The mergedObject therefore does not include the first four keys from object1, as they are overwritten by the values from object2.

But typescript doesn't throw any exception when you use one of the first 4 values from object1..?

```js
const object1 = {
    one: 'hey brother',
    two: 'hi bro',
    three: 'how are you?',
    four: 'good thanks',
    five: 'Great',
    six: 'bye'
} as const

const object2 = { 
    one: 'wrong',
    two: 'falsch',
    three: 'right',
    four: 'recht'
} as const

const mergedObjects = {
    ...Object.values(object1),
    ...Object.values(object2)
} as const

type MergedObjectValue = (typeof mergedObjects)[number]

const tryThis = (value: MergedObjectValue) => {
    // do nada
}

console.log("mergedObjects", mergedObjects)

// TS is happy with both of these
tryThis('hey brother') // this is not in the mergedObjects
tryThis('wrong') // this is

// TS is not happy with this
tryThis('this is not in either')
```

I would expect TS to raise concerns when `tryThis(object1.one)` is written! Can someone explain the reasoning here? I'm not after anyone telling how to do things differently, this is merely an example I found, and I would like to know what's happening behind the scenes!

Answer (score 3):

The spread operator doesn't keep the index value on the signature :

```
{...Object.values(object1)}
```

is of type  :

```
[x: number]: "hey brother" | "hi bro" | "how are you?" | "good thanks" | "Great" | "bye";
```

You see, only `[x: number]`

So the merged type is

```
{
    readonly [x: number]: "hey brother" | "hi bro" | "how are you?" | "good thanks" | "Great" | "bye" | "wrong" | "falsch" | "right" | "recht";
}
```

Which is why the compiler doesn't complain on something that should not be valid.

Comment: That makes sense a lot of sense, maybe it's not as weird as I thought, merely slightly unusual!

Answer (score 1):

The difference in criteria between you and TS compiler comes from this line:

```
type MergedObjectValue = (typeof mergedObjects)[number]
```

When interpreting this line, TS doesn't takes into account the actual value of `mergedObjects`, but only it's possible values given the code. Basically, TS isn't smart enough to realize that, in this particular example, `object1.one` would never be actually present in `mergedObjects`, but it does type analysis concluding that it would be one of all those keys, ignoring the fact that some would be overriden.

The result would be the same if you invert the spreads when merging.

When in doubt about types always ask your IDE about the real types of variables, there you would find what TS actually calculated, ending up in *Matthieu Riegler* answer.

Comment: I figured something like "TS isn't smart enough to.." haha. But yeah, irrelevant case really, just took me by surprise a little when I came across the code. Thanks!